# Array syntax in JSON in rails 3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following controller code:

```
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.where("(first_name || ' ' || last_name) ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    @autolist = []
    @profiles.each do |profile|
      user = User.find_by_id(profile.user_id)
      @autolist.concat([{"id",profile.id,"name",profile.first_name+" "+profile.last_name,"email",user.email}])
    end    

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @autolist }
      end
  end
```

It works in my local environment, but crashes my app. Specifically this line:  `@autolist.concat([{"id",profile.id,"name",profile.first_name+" "+profile.last_name,"email",user.email}])`

Any ideas?

I have a feeling it has to do with my local env using ruby 1.8.7 and the heroku app running 1.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in 1.8.7:

```
>> h = {"id", 6}
=> {"id"=>6}
```

but not in 1.9.2:

```
>>  h = {"id",6}
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
 h = {"id",6}
           ^
    from /Users/mu/Developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

The rocket notation will serve you better:

```
@autolist.concat([{ "id" => profile.id, "name" => profile.first_name + " " + profile.last_name, "email" => user.email}])
```

I can't find any mention of this change in the 1.9.1 or 1.9.2 release notes and this is actually the first time I've seen the `{'a', b}` syntax for a Ruby Hash. Perhaps that notation was a deprecated feature that finally went away.

BTW, developing on 1.8.7 and deploying on 1.9.2 isn't the best idea.